# aws lamda with boto3.client - read output from dict and

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3

i hope you can help me
after a get a response 200 ok  from aws lambda, i want to search all DestinationCidrBlock that are in the Routes 
but when a print it i get only the first one

```
u'Routes': [{u'Origin': 'CreateRoute', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '1.1.1.1/32', u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-08b854f5bc83cefe4', u'State': 'blackhole'}, {u'Origin': 'CreateRoute', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '2.2.2.2/32', u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-08b854f5bc83cefe4', u'State': 'blackhole'}, {u'GatewayId': 'local', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '172.31.0.0/16', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'CreateRouteTable'}, {u'GatewayId': 'igw-cec16ba6', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '0.0.0.0/0', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'CreateRoute'}]}]}
```

if i make it in this way i get the values but not the 2.2.2.2/32:

```
print response["RouteTables"][0]['Routes'][0]['DestinationCidrBlock']

print response["RouteTables"][0]['RouteTableId']
```

1.1.1.1/32

rtb-08c31263

but if a make a for loop in there i get the numbers in this format

```
for x in response["RouteTables"][0]['Routes'][0]['DestinationCidrBlock']:
print x
```

1

.

1

.

1

.

1

/

3

2

so my question and i hope you can help me is how can a get all the ip address in there and store in some kind
associate the ip and the route table id in a some kind of dict or list to get all the data in well format

Comment: Please use some code formatting to make the post more legible.

Answer (score 0):

`["RouteTables"][0]` holds the first route table returned by the result, if you have only one route table then you can do it like that but if you have more route tables and need to consider each one of them then you will need to loop through the contents of `["RouteTables"]` as well.

I will assume that you have only one route table.

You have already obtained route table id from

```
["RouteTables"][0]["RouteTableId"]
```

If you want to extract each destination cidr blocks you will need to loop through

```
["RouteTables"][0]["Routes"]
```

and while looping, extract those cidr blocks, i.e

```
cirdBlocks = [route["DestinationCidrBlock"] for route in response["RouteTables"][0]["Routes"]]
```

To create a dictionary with key being route table ID and value being the above cidr blocks, you can simply do the following

```
routeTableId = response["RouteTables"][0]["RouteTableId"]
cirdBlocks = [route["DestinationCidrBlock"] for route in response["RouteTables"][0]["Routes"]]
routeTableCidrAssoc = { routeTableId: cirdBlocks }
```